# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Medical Sciences's [first moderator election](https://health.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the new moderator is:

[image: Carey Gregory]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://health.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Since this is a [*Pro Tempore* election](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/983/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election) and since there was just one nominee, we've skipped the voting stage.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations!

> May you enjoy life and art, respected while you serve as a Pro-Tempore
>   Moderator and remembered with affection thereafter. May you always act
>   so as to preserve the finest traditions of your calling and may you
>   long experience the joy of helping those who seek our help.

Comment: Thanks! Comments must be 15 characters in length, so....